# How to add the values dynamically to cells of the TStringGrid in delphi?

Tags: delphi

```
proedure TForm5.ButtonClick(Sender:TObject);
var
  I, J: Integer;
const
  MyArray: array [1..5] of string = ('Siva', 'jindal', 'ram', 'kesu', 'Srinu ');
begin
  StringGrid1.RowCount := StringGrid1.RowCount + 1;
  for J := 1 to length(MyArray);
  for I := 0 to
    StringGrid1.Cells[I,StringGrid1.RowCount-1] := MyArray[J];

  StringGrid1.Row := StringGrid.RowCount-1;
end;
```

In This i am able to create dynamically rows but unable to insert the values of the array into the cells..

Comment: This code doesn't even compile?

Comment: You have a mistake in the second for-loop

Comment: How many columns does the grid have?

Comment: I think you should [read this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Declarations_and_Statements#For_Statements)

Comment: You have errors in three of the four lines of code you posted between `begin` and `end`, and two of those three lines contain errors that would prevent the code from even compiling. Ergo, this is **not** your real code. If you want us to help figure out why your code isn't working, **post your code**. Making it up as you go leads to introducing new errors (which clearly happened here, in an **extreme** example) and can hide the actual problem. Posting nonsense like you have here is simply useless.

Answer (score 5):

Try something more like this instead:

```
procedure TForm5.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  MyArray: array[1..5] of string = ('Siva', 'jindal', 'ram', 'kesu', 'Srinu ');
var
  I, Row: Integer;
begin
  Row := StringGrid1.RowCount;
  StringGrid1.RowCount := Row + 1;
  for I := Low(MyArray) to High(MyArray) do
    StringGrid1.Cells[I-1, Row] := MyArray[I];
  StringGrid1.Row := Row;
end;
```